# Bazel: how to get a value from the --config flag to use it in a genrule()?

Tags: python, bazel

The build command is looks like:
`bazel build //... --config=x86_64 --config=variant`

There are several 'variant'-s defined in the root BUILD file. As example:

```
config_setting(
    name = "premium",
    flag_values = {
        ":system": "premium",
        "@blah-blah//:variant": "star35",
        ":hardware": "premium+",
    },
)
config_setting(
    name = "premium+",
    flag_values = {
        ":system": "premium+",
        "@blah-blah//:variant": "star3",
        ":hardware": "premium+",
    },
)
```

According to selected `variant` in the build-command, different **config_setting** will be called with different values. I want to create a **genrule()** which will take the **variant** from the commandline, get appropriate **config_setting** and get needed **value** to write it to a version_manifest.txt file.

There is a problem: it can be several --config flags (like in the example above). So, I need to check just that configs that will correspond to the needed variant-list.

How can I get selected value **--config=variant** and how I can use the value I've got to get values from the **config_setting** in the created genrule()?

What I have at the moment:
**variant_info_extension.bzl**

```
def _get_config_values_impl(ctx):
    config_values = select({
        config: ctx.attr.config
        for config in ctx.attr.config.split()
        if config in ["premium",
                      "premium+",
                      "base",
                      "base+"]
    })
    return [
        getattr(config_values[config], ":system"),
        getattr(config_values[config], "@blah-blah//:variant"),
        getattr(config_values[config], ":hardware"),
        getattr(config_values[config], ":ecu")
    ]
    
def get_config_values(config_setting):
    return rule(
        outputs = [],
        implementation = _get_config_values_impl,
        attrs = {
            "config": config_setting,
        },
    )
```

**genrule() in the BUILD file**

```
CONFIGS = "$(CONFIGS)"
get_config_values(CONFIGS)
genrule(
    name = "add_variant_information",
    outs = ["version_manifest.txt"],
    cmd = """
        values=$$(location :get_config_values)
        IFS=' ' read -ra config_array <<< "$$values"
        for config in $${config_array[@]}; do
            system=$$(echo $${config} | cut -d' ' -f1)
            variant=$$(echo $${config} | cut -d' ' -f2)
            hw=$$(echo $${config} | cut -d' ' -f3)
            ecu=$$(echo $${config} | cut -d' ' -f4)
            echo "system=$$system" >> $(location version_manifest.txt)
            echo "variant=$$variant" >> $(location version_manifest.txt)
            echo "hw=$$hw" >> $(location version_manifest.txt)
            echo "ecu=$$ecu" >> $(location version_manifest.txt)
        done
    """,
    attrs = {
        "config": CONFIGS,
    },
    output_to_bind = [],
)
```

But I see an error in the output:
`Error in rule: got dict<string, string> for 'attrs', want dict<string, Attribute>`

It seems like I'm doing something wrong.